# Polymer Navigation - How do I modify main content when sidebar link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, polymer, single-page-application

I'm using the Polymer core-drawer-panel to create a single page app with some content and a slide-out sidebar for navigation.

How do I modify the content of the `<div class="content">` when `<paper-item>`s are clicked? What is the PolymerJS best-practice for this?

For example:
If "First Item" is clicked I want the div to read "Hey this is first item content".
If "Second Item" is clicked I want the div to read "Hey this is second item content".

Here's the code I got from the [polymer example](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/layout-elements.html#responsive-side-nav) with small modifications (paper-item instead of core-item and name changes):

HTML:

```
<core-header-panel drawer>
  <core-toolbar id="navheader'">
    <span>Menu</span>
  </core-toolbar>
  <core-menu>
    <paper-item label="First Item"></paper-item>
    <paper-item label="Second Item"></paper-item>
  </core-menu>
 </core-header-panel>

<core-header-panel main>
  <core-toolbar id="mainheader">
    <paper-icon-button 
      id="navicon" icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
    <span flex>Title</span>
  </core-toolbar>
  <div class="content">
    Hey, this is my main content

  </div>
</core-header-panel>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
  var navicon = document.getElementById('navicon');
  var drawerPanel = document.getElementById('drawerPanel');
  navicon.addEventListener('click', function() {
    drawerPanel.togglePanel();
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
core-header-panel {
  background: white;
}
core-toolbar {
  background-color: #03A9F4;
}
#navheader {
  background-color: #56BA89;
}
.content {
  padding: 20px;
}
/* drawer is always visible on a wide screen
   so menu button isn't required */
core-drawer-panel:not([narrow]) #navicon {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im not sure if you are talking about single page apps or not. On the FAQ there is a section of SPA and they suggest using flatiron-director to handle navigation. 
I followed an example I found and it was pretty simple.

https://github.com/ebidel/polymer-change/blob/master/demos/spa.html

https://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html

Nice article on how to create a SPA: https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/spa.html

Example:

```
    <core-header-panel navigation flex mode="seamed">
       <core-toolbar style="background-color: #526E9C; color: #fff;">vanilla polymer demo</core-toolbar>
        <core-menu>
            <core-item icon="settings" label="Dashboard"><a href="#dashboard"></a></core-item>
            <core-item icon="settings" label="Flow Analysis"><a href="#flow"></a></core-item>
            <core-item icon="settings" label="Alerts"><a href="#alerts"></a></core-item>
        </core-menu>
    </core-header-panel>

    <div tool>Polymer App - {{route}}</div>

    <div class="content">

        <core-pages selected="{{route}}" valueattr="hash">
            <div hash="">
                Default page
            </div>
            <div hash="dashboard">
                <revenue-dashboard></revenue-dashboard>
            </div>
            <div hash="flow">
                <flow-analysis></flow-analysis>
            </div>
            <div hash="alerts">
                <alerts-page></alerts-page>
            </div>
        </core-pages>

    </div>
```

Comment: Based on your answer I tried following the spa.html demo. I modified a couple things so that the page content would be different from the page.name but how do I make the page.content an external html file or polymer element? I'm assuming that't the polymer way.
http://jsbin.com/deqifinoqimi/1/ doesn't really work due to importing the polymer elements but has ebidel's demo code modified with page.content added.

Comment: I've updated my explanation providing an example. the way I've included  pages is by creating new elements. See above

Comment: Your example doesn't use the flatiron-director though. Isn't that the Polymer way of doing things?

Comment: I clearly failed to paste the flat iron lines. My bad! Anyhow, polymer team just created an article on SPA and flatiron usage. Im updating the response with link

Answer (score 1):

After more searching I found [GDG Beijing's Polymer site](http://devfest.gdgbeijing.org/) and the code for it on [GitHub](https://github.com/gdgbeijing/devfest2014)

I managed to get it to work using `core-animated-pages` and their `hash_nav()` function. I'm not sure if this is the "Best-practice" for PolymerJS navigation so I would love to see other people's comments/answers.

Here is the new HTML and JS thanks to their code:

HTML:

```
      <core-header-panel drawer>
        <core-toolbar id="navheader'">
          <span>Menu</span>
        </core-toolbar>
        <core-menu id="nav_menu" selected="0">
          <paper-item label="Home"><a href="#"></a></paper-item>
          <paper-item label="First Item"><a href="#first"></a></paper-item>
          <paper-item label="Second Item"><a href="#second"></a></paper-item>
        </core-menu>
       </core-header-panel>

      <core-header-panel main>
        <core-toolbar id="mainheader">
          <paper-icon-button 
            id="navicon" icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
          <span flex>Title</span>
        </core-toolbar>
        <div id="content-container">
          <core-animated-pages id="content-pages" selected="0">
            <section>
              Home content
            </section>

            <section>
              First content
            </section>

            <section>
              Second content
            </section>

          </core-animated-pages>
        </div>

      </core-header-panel>

    </core-drawer-panel>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
 var navicon = document.getElementById('navicon');
 var drawerPanel = document.getElementById('drawerPanel');
 navicon.addEventListener('click', function() {
   drawerPanel.togglePanel();
 });

 window.onhashchange=hash_nav;
});

function hash_nav() { 
  var nav_links = document.querySelectorAll('core-menu paper-item a');
  for(var i = 0; i < nav_links.length; i++){
    if(nav_links[i].hash === window.location.hash){
      document.querySelector('#nav_menu').selected = i;
      document.querySelector('#content-pages').selected = i;
      document.getElementById('drawerPanel').togglePanel();

      break;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: You should data-bind the core-animated-pages and core-menu selected attributes together. <core-animated-pages selected="{{selected}}">  and <core-menu selected="{{selected}}">

Comment: I would then also need to instantiate selected ="0" right? Where should I do that?

Also does this mean that this is a good way of handling navigation in single paged apps or should I be using flatiron-director like the FAQ and user1707689 suggest?